# How can I implement OAuth2 for sending emails

Tags: emails, google

I want to send emails using Smtp.gmail.com with oauth2 support, but I couldn't find any explanation. Everyone seems to avoid discussing this, and the few questions about it have not been answered concretely and visibly. An example is that there is no such question on Stack Exchange.

As far as I know, Google wanted to stop the method of connecting outside of Oauth in February 2021, but due to the pandemic this did not happen. I thought Joomla 4.X would support Oauth2, but it didn't. So I started looking and I saw that Joomla uses PHPMailer so I searched and made a script to send an email using smtp and connecting through the oauth2 method.

Now I don't know how to use this script in Joomla.

My question is can I use it? Or I can use it in the script used by Joomla to send emails to enter the connection oauth2, as a connection method, and the client ID, secret.

I have no idea where this script is. Anyone can help me with some suggestions:

Where can I find the script used by Joomla to send emails?

P.S. This message was written with Google translate, because I don't know English very well.